# got error when run cmd RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, manageiq

I'm trying to convert manageiq development mode to production mode so I applied precompile cmd and got error

> ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)
>   (line: 2221, col: 46, pos: 3996497)
>
> Error
>       at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3623:11948)
>       at js_error (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3623:12167)
>       at croak (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3623:22038)
>       at token_error (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3623:22175)
>       at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3623:22263)
>       at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3623:31244)
>       at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3624:1752)
>       at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3624:2523)
>       at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3624:2615)
>       at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20190527-22386-1jyom7qjs:3624:3058)

manageiq running in development mode correctly but unable to precompile the assets(which consist of JS, CSS files)

manageIq should compile properly and should start in production mode and generate production log

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
cd /var/www/miq/vmdb
bin/update
```

---

`rake assets:precompile` is only a part of what needs to happen, and `bin/update` does that as well as a number of other things.

Comment: got answer for this to make changes in production.rb so as to ignore js file conversion